# Firefox remember password for single site

Tags: firefox, passwords

generally I don't save my passwords but for one particular site I would like to in firefox. Is there a way to save a password for a single site, without being prompted for every other site that has passwords? Or is there an extension/plugin I could use to do this?

thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, you can save it for that one site then disable the Password remembering.
Another way, since Firefox's password manager is so insecure that you can access it without even booting into your OS, even *with* a master password, is to use KeePass, which fakes keystrokes to enter your password in on-demand. Much more secure.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the very same problem on many sites. Sick of having to type it in every time I visited the site without being able to just click a button, I eventually discovered the 'Secure Login' add-on. One button click and your in.

I also have 'Saved Password Editor', another Firefox add-on. Handy for those really awkward sites.

Hope this helps.