# Remember passwords for specified sites in Firefox 5

Tags: passwords, firefox

There is an option in Firefox to exclude sites from saving passwords, but I need exact opposite functionality - to save passwords only for sites I specify. Is it possible to achive such functionality?

P.S. I'm aware of [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/177675/firefox-remember-password-for-single-site), but it's solution doesn't work, at least for FF5. If I disable password remembering, it won't automatically fill username/password for that site anymore (even though it's still in FF database of saved passwords).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is still no such functionality in Firefox (I'm currently on FF 17 beta). So you are only limited to the method of exclusion sites for which you don't need to save password.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with using an addon, then a hack might work with the stored passwords in FF.

Step 1: Enable Remember Passwords for sites in FF

Step 2: Log in to your website. Click on Remember Password for this website.

Step 3: Install [SecureLogin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/secure-login). It uses the same database of stored passwords as FF.

Step 4: Disable Remember Passwords for sites under Preferences

Step 5: When you visit your website, click on the orange key on you Navigation toolbar or Alt + N (default shortcut for SecureLogin).